# Что такое for в bootstrap 4, type, id =""

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Изучаю bootstrap 4
Есть несколько строк:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
  <label for="email">О себе</label> 
  <input type="email"class="form-control"id="email" placeholder="Имею опыт работы с код ревью, работал тим лидом в компании ххх, умею печь пироги"name="email" required> 
  <div class="valid-feedback">Valid</div> 
  <div class="invalid-feedback"> 
    Please fill this field 
  </div>
```

Что значит `for='email'`? Для чего `for`?

`Type` и `id` - Что с ними? 
Не нашел в документации места, где можно узнать список всех типов, рода логин, номер телефона, емаил.

Что служит для проверки на регулярки, а что на нечто другое? Не понимаю смысл этих строк

Comment: справочник по HTML откройте, бутстрап тут ни при чем.

Comment: Это не до бутстрапа относится а до HTML5 http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/type ,
http://htmlbook.ru/html/label/for , http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/id